# c# Determine button function according to previous action

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement, panel

I have one Win Form with four Panels in it, where each panel will only be seeing separately as if they were independent forms, so I created a function to control it.

```
  public void panelView(int pw)
 {
   if (pw == 1)
  {
  panelMenu.Visible == true;     /*panelMenu - this is the main menu*/
  panel2.Visible == false;       /*panel2 - has a textBox and an "OK" button*/
  panel3.Visible == false;       /*panel3 - is where you see a product details*/
  panel4.Visible == false;       /*panel4 - is where you see products within a order*/
  }
   if (pw == 2)
  {      
  panelMenu.Visible == false;
  panel2.Visible == true;
  panel3.Visible == false;
  panel4.Visible == false;
  }
   if (pw == 3)
  {      
  panelMenu.Visible == false;
  panel2.Visible == false;
  panel3.Visible == true;
  panel4.Visible == false;
  }
   if (pw == 4)
  {      
  panelMenu.Visible == false;
  panel2.Visible == false;
  panel3.Visible == false;
  panel4.Visible == true;
  }
}

  private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     panelView(2);
   }

  private void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     panelView(2);
   }
```

So when I click on "btnCheck", it goes to "panel2" where I can input the product code, so than I press "OK" which will send a message to the server requesting product details for that specific product's and show all the product details on "panel3".

If I decided to check items within an order, instead of pressing "btnCheck", I would press "btnOrder", which would also lead to "panel2" where I would input the order code, but when I press "OK", this time I want it to have a different function where instead of it requesting the server for product details for the code entered on "panel2", it would request for all the items within the order corresponding to the order code entered on "panel2", than this information would be shown on "panel4".

I just don't know how to let "panel2" know what I clicked on "panelMenu" so the "OK" button can take the textBox.Text and perform the task chose in the "panelMenu". Help?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Let's say you need to post some code.

Comment: I have edited it with some code and more details about my issue, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to pass your panelView method an additional parameter, which indicates the state in which you want a particular panel to appear. If you're only going to have two possible states for Panel 2, this could be an int or a boolean, but you might be better off defining some kind of state [enum](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum) if there are eventually going to be multiple states per panel.

For example:

```
public void panelView(int pw, int state)
{
    switch (pw)
    {
        case 1:
            // stuff
            break;
        case 2: 
            if (state == 1) // Check
            {
                // check setup code
            }
            else // Order
            {
                // order setup code
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        // stuff
        break; 

        // etc. etc.
    }
}
```

So, when calling from btnCheck you could do it like so:

```
panelView(2, 1);
```

..and when from btnOrder:

```
panelView(2, 2);
```

I highly recommend you make the states more readable somehow though, if you're not going to use enums maybe define some constants that you pass in to makes things more readable:

```
int OrderState = 2;
int CheckState = 1;
panelView(2, OrderState)
```

If you have public properties on your panels, you can set flags which then control how they behave depending on the state that was specified.